# How to play back non-audio CD content of an "Enhanced CD"/"CD+" under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, compact-disc

I have an Audio CD which has "Compact Disc +" and "CD Extra" logos on its cover. So I guess this CD conforms to the *Blue Book* standard.

When I put this CD in my Windows 7 computer, I can listen to the audio tracks. And the last track seems to be the *CD+* data track.

Windows Explorer shows data contents:

- A directory `CDPLUS` with files `INFO.CDP` and `SUB_INFO.EN`.
- A directory `PICTURES` with files `JACKET01.00J`, `JACKET01.00N`, `JACKET01.00S`, and `JACKET01.00T`

Is there a program for Windows 7 that can interpret this data contents?

Comment: Doesn't Windows Media Player make use of them to show you song/artist names and a cover picture or so?

Comment: I gave Windows Media Player a try, but it didn't give any data except the audio CD content.

Comment: I think it used to work (WinXP or before). It's just the support is probably dropped since no one make such disc these days and apparently it requires licensing from Philips(/Sony).

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue on both my Windows 7 desktop and my Windows 8.1 laptop with an album from Suzanne Ciani named Pianissimo II that was released in 1996.  It is marked Multimedia Enhanced and the instructions say to use Windows Explorer to navigate to the disk and double click on the file 'pianoii.exe'.  Well no file shows up on any of the versions of directory explorer I have on either machine.  These were instructions for Win95.

I finally did find a solution that might help others.  I downloaded a program called ISO Buster from Major Geeks.  It is designed for data recovery but works for copying files of any CD (or DVD I think) and it saw and copied to my hard disk the video from this CD.  It ended up as a .mpg file which is fine with me.  I can convert it to a .mp4 to play on my TV when I want to.